# Why is my WIFI not working if other computers connect to it wirelessly?

Tags: wireless-networking

I don't know why my WIFI is having a problem if other laptops connect to it. Should I buy a wireless extender? I think its not because of the router's range because when no one is connected to my network it reaches my room with 4 bars. But when my sister connects her laptop to the wireless network then my connection drops randomly.

Comment: What channel is your wireless network being broadcast on?  Have you checked the router configuration?  Are there a lot of other wireless networks in your area?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the number of clients to connect your internet via wireless ADSL Router or modem ,
I have showed example of my WIFI modem config window screen shot,  hope you know to access your modem and try this.

[image]